# A friend received receipts from visa transactions, but her name was forged to obtain the card

Tags: credit-card, fraud

My friend's husband has a long history of forging her name to obtain credit cards in either her name alone, or for joint account cards. He never gives her the cards or their numbers, but racks up charges on them and then declares bankruptcy.

She has put a freeze with the credit bureau on his[her husbands] ability to do this again.

This week, she again got email receipts for $5,000 total on a Visa card she doesn't recognize. Only the last 4 digits and the Auth code are on the receipts.

Her updated credit report shows no visa with these 4 numbers under her name. These receipts were sent to her by the merchant who took the money. Turns out it's a lawyer's retainer fee.

Her husband is hiring an attorney to fight a divorce judgement she has against him. i.e., the judge has ruled in her favour.

She called this attorney. He told her the money was drawn from a joint account. But there's no way to know for sure.

- Is it possible her husband obtained a card from a bank overseas?
- Is that why she can't find it on the credit report?
- If he got the card recently, she has a freeze in effect and no bank
  can issue a card in her name without her approval. How is this guy
  still able to get a card in her name?

Comment: Can you edit and add country tag.

Comment: This is not much a case of personal finance as it is a case of identity theft and fraud. You need to state the country.

Comment: @Mindwin identity theft questions are still considered [on topic here](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2459/are-questions-about-identity-theft-on-topic). They don't really fit anywhere else in Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible her husband obtained a card from a bank overseas?

Unlikely. A Bank overseas generally will not issue such cards.

> Is that why she can't find it on the credit report?

The data sent to Credit Bureau is periodic and not immediate. At times it may take a month or more for a Bank to start reporting the new card to Credit Agencies.

> If he got the card recently, she has a freeze in effect and no bank can issue a card in her name without her approval.

Possibly timing issue. i.e. the freeze was put after card company pulled the report and approved. It may take sometime to dispatch a new card. So it could be that her husband applied for this card previously before the freeze was put in place.